# photoshop save all open jpegs script

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I have to crop all open psd files and save as jpg.

To speed up the workflow I am using a photoshop script that allows me to save the files one by one with specific jpg options.

I would like to enhanced the script by including a save all open files feature.

What would be the simples way to add this functionality to the script using javascript?

This is the structure of the script

//flatten image

//declare variable myJPEGOptions
//input jpg options

//save jpg to folder path

//close the document

Comment: Better suited for http://photo.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The photo.stack.exchange forum seems focused on photography gear. My questions is about javascript tools. I would like to find out which javascript tool can accomplish a close all open documents.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use Automate. You don't need to included anything special.

- Write your script as you would normally with the intention of processing just one file.(which will flatten, process save and then close the document) as normal.
- Then access your script in batch mode (File > Automate > Batch)
- Select the your script and a folder with all your documents in.

Or if you want to modify your script you can:

```
  // get all the files to process
  var inFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Please select folder to process");
  if (inFolder != null)
  {
    var fileList = inFolder.getFiles();
  }

// and then loop over the file list

for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
{
    var doc = open(fileList[i]);
    // process files here
    // close files here
}
```

Just bare in mind that Photoshop will try to open any file in that list including things that it can't like text files or thumbnails thumbs.db :)